# jQuery keep div shown on goback

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form select input, and when the value = 1, jquery shows a div.
When someone goes back to the page from the next page, the div is not shown yet the value of the select input is 1.

How can i keep it showing on page back?

At the moment i have this:

```
$j('#sla').on('change', function(){
    if(this.value==1)
    {
        $j('.solHide').css('width', '100%');
        $j('.solHide').fadeIn('fast');
        $j('.detMsg').fadeIn('fast');
    }
    else
    {
        $j('.solHide').fadeOut('fast');
        $j('.detMsg').fadeOut('fast');
        //$j('#vatHide').hide();
    }
});
```

Which shows the div on change.

Comment: When you navigate back, the value has not changed so the event is never fired

Comment: Did you try doing the same (`if(this.va...`) on page `ready`/`load`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just trigger the change event for the #sla when the document is ready.

```
$(function(){ 
    $( "#sla" ).trigger( "change" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just trigger the change on page load:

```
$j('#sla').on('change', function(){
    if(this.value==1)
    {
        $j('.solHide').css('width', '100%');
        $j('.solHide').fadeIn('fast');
        $j('.detMsg').fadeIn('fast');
    }
    else
    {
        $j('.solHide').fadeOut('fast');
        $j('.detMsg').fadeOut('fast');
        //$j('#vatHide').hide();
    }
}).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add also the load event for the handler.

```
$j('#sla').on('change load', function(){
    if(this.value==1)
    {
        $j('.solHide').css('width', '100%');
        $j('.solHide').fadeIn('fast');
        $j('.detMsg').fadeIn('fast');
    }
    else
    {
        $j('.solHide').fadeOut('fast');
        $j('.detMsg').fadeOut('fast');
        //$j('#vatHide').hide();
    }
});
```